# Trying to use lxml to return the text inside of the tags

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to use lxml to return the text inside of the tags `<ImageSet><LargeImage><URL>this text</URL></LargeImage></ImageSet>` my code only returns None for the text under each  tag.

Here is my code:

```
# I am trying to get the URL text using lxml

for attr_list in tree.iterfind(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"ImageSet"):
    for image_list in tree.find(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"LargeImage"):
        print(etree.tostring(image_list))
        print(image_list.findtext(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"URL")) # This is only printing None.
```

Here is the code output:

```
<URL xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01">http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg</URL>
None
<Height xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">500</Height>
None
<Width xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">349</Width>
None
<URL xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01">http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg</URL>
None
<Height xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">500</Height>
None
<Width xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">349</Width>
None
<URL xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01">http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg</URL>
None
<Height xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">500</Height>
None
<Width xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">349</Width>
None
<URL xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01">http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg</URL>
None
<Height xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">500</Height>
None
<Width xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">349</Width>
None
<URL xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01">http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg</URL>
None
<Height xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">500</Height>
None
<Width xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">349</Width>
None
<URL xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01">http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg</URL>
None
<Height xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01" Units="pixels">500</Height>
```

Lines #11, 17, 23, etc... should show a URL and not None.

**Edit 1: Let me try to clarify my above question...**

This is the code I am using:

```
for item in tree.iterfind(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"ImageSet"):
    for image_set in item.find(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"LargeImage"):
        print(etree.tostring(image_set))
```

This is the output I get:
http://dpaste.com/289187/

How do I specifically get the content inside the URL tags?

I have tried the following (none of them work, though, but maybe you guys can see the general idea of what I am trying to do from my failed attempts):

```
for item in tree.iterfind(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"ImageSet"):
    for image_set in item.find(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"LargeImage"):
        for image_url_set in image_set.find(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"URL"):
            print(etree.tostring(image_url_set))
```

Here's the error I get:

for image_url_set in image_set.find(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"URL"):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
for item in tree.iterfind(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"ImageSet"):
    for image_set in item.find(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"LargeImage"):
        for image_link in image_set.iter(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"URL"):
            print(image_link.text)
```

Nothing even prints with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree

URL_TAG = "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01}URL"

tree = etree.fromstring(body)
print tree.findtext(".//%s" % (URL_TAG,)) # 1st way

for ev, el in etree.iterparse(StringIO(body), tag=URL_TAG): # 2nd approach
    print el.text
```

Where `body` is your xml-text.

#### Output

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51dSYJcTaTL.jpg
```

Comment: This seems to find every URL tag in the XML document. I have many URL tags in the XML document, some that are links to the product page, some are links to the small image, and some are links to the large image.

Comment: @Kelp: Note: 1. there is `{}` around the namespace in the tag 2. `.//` is not part of the tag.

Comment: @Kelp: you could use `etree.iterparse` to find all `ImageSet` elements in the document and `image_set.xpath('ns:LargeImage/ns:URL/text()', namespaces=dict(ns=settings.AMAZON_NS))` to find text inside `ImageSet/LargeImage/URL`.

Comment: Ah, I am coming up short again. In this code: http://dpaste.com/289299/, lines 1-13 show how I got elements of my Image Sets. Lines 16-29 show my actual code at using Xpath on those elements. All I am getting is empty lists. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Kelp: 1. try `...namespaces=dict(ns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01")` i.e., don't include `{}` in the namespace. `{}` is a special syntax that delimits namespace in a tag; the braces are not part of the namespace. 2. If you already has `tree` element then you could extract all urls text in a single `.xpath('//ns:ImageSet/ns:LargeImage/ns:URL/text()', namespaces...)` call without `.iterfind()`.

Comment: Hello, that worked very well. Thank you. Also, do you know if iterfind or xpath is faster, or is it situational?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
print(image_list.findtext(".//"+settings.AMAZON_NS+"URL"))
```

with just

```
print(image_list.text)
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to only retrieve the contents of the <URL> tag. When I replace it with print(image_list.text), I get everything in <LargeImage>: http://dpaste.com/289113/. I get URL, Height, and Width. I only want URL.